# How to send a multicast over the wifi tethering network?

Tags: java, android, networking, multicast

I'm building an app to send a multicast message from all the devices to 224.0.0.1 so that every 1 in the network can receive it. But once i set up a tethering network and let all the devices join the network and do the multicast only the hosting device does not receive the multicast and other devices does not receive tethering hosting device multicast. How can i make the tethering device also receive multicast data packets?

Comment: maybe some help: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=51195  - can you confirm that all the devices you are testing with support multicast?  There are some apps that test this.

Comment: yes. All the devices are supporting multicast. its working fine when its connected to a normal router hosted wifi network. and even when other devices are connected to the tethering hosting device they detect each others data packets. only the hosting device do not receive them.